# iOS with Redpark serial cable compile error

Tags: iphone, ios, serial-port

I'm very new to iOS coding and I've been practicing with little app examples found online.

I'm reading examples in the "iOS Sensor Apps with Arduino" book and I've been following instructions for the serial communication example with the Adruino UNO board using the Redpark serial cable for the iPhone/iPad

I have the Redpark serial cable and their demo app, and a registered working developer profile.  I've been able to communicate over serial with the demo app on the iPhone and the serial port on my computer.

In working with the example from the book and I've copied in this line to the iOS code:

```
bytesRead = [rscMgr read:rxBuffer length:numBytes];
```

However, when compiling this with the rest of the code it throws an error described as

**Use of undeclared identifier "if"**

I've looked everywhere for the word "if" and can't find it.  I've also looked at the sample code from Redpark and the is similar if not identical, except for the buffer name.

Please let me know if I've provided enough detail and I'm forward to any advice this community may have, thanks again for offering your time.

Bellow is more of the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    rscMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];
    [rscMgr setDelegate:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)sendString:(id)sender {
    [self.textEntry resignFirstResponder];
    //Add code here
}

#pragma mark - RscMgrDelegate methods
- (void)cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol {
    [rscMgr setBaud:9600];
    [rscMgr open];
}
- (void)cableDisconnected {
}
- (void)portStatusChanged {

- (void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)numBytes {
    int bytesRead;
    // Read the data out
    **bytesRead = [rscMgr read:rxBuffer length:numBytes];**
    NSLog( @"Read %d bytes from serial cable.", bytesRead);
    for(int i = 0;i < numBytes;++i) {
    lf.serialView.text =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c",
    self.textView.text,
    ((char *)rxBuffer)[i]];
    }
}
- (BOOL) rscMessageReceived:(UInt8 *)msg TotalLength:(int)len {
    return FALSE;
}
- (void) didReceivePortConfig {
}
@end
```

Comment: Is your code hosted anywhere (complete with `.xcodeproj` etc.)? I could check it out and see if I get the same error.